# Konami Code Help – Two Different KeyDown Inputs

Tags: javascript, keydown

I want to implement the Konami code on my webpage. I came across this easy-to-use javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( window.addEventListener ) {
  var state = 0, konami = [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65];
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if ( e.keyCode == konami[state] ) state++;
    else state = 0;
    if ( state == 10 )
      window.location = "http://www.konami.com/";
    }, true);
}
</script>
```

However, on my webpage I want to have to have two different inputs that lead to two different websites. For example: if someone enters the [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65] Konami sequence on their keyboard, then I want them to be redirected to "http://www.konami.com/". But if someone enters **google** on their keyboard (i.e. 71,79,79,71,76,69) instead, then I want them to be redirected to "http://www.google.com/".

Can someone please tell me how I can achieve this by altering the javascript above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( window.addEventListener ) {
  var state1 = 0, konami = [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65];
  var state2 = 0, google = [71,79,79,71,76,69];
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if ( e.keyCode == konami[state1] ) state1++;
    else state1 = 0;
    if ( e.keyCode == google[state2] ) state2++;
    else state2 = 0;
    if ( state1 == 10 )
      window.location = "http://www.konami.com/";
    if ( state2 == 6 )
      window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    }, true);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much Balthus – I really appreciate it!